# What is an alternative to Bamboo environments in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, bamboo, continuous-delivery

I like Bamboo idea of environments connected to deployment plans as it gives nice overview what is deployed where.

Is there are canonical way to look over deployment environments in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/deploy-dashboard/ which can show you the latest version with a history for each of your environments. However, this needs to be triggered manually from a deployment job. This is nowhere close to what Bamboo offers.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Can't believe it has only 135 installations. 
Thank you!

Comment: @krubar let me know how it played out for you, what was missing, what workaround you had to make.